How to program chrome extension for a cookie's expiration date later with Chrome?
I often connect a website with a session cookie which expires after 5 mintues. This is annoying because I am required to re-login very often.
How to program chrome extensions, make its expiration date to a later date or refresh cookie every 5 mintes?
Thanks

For a well written website, make its expiration date to a later date shouldn't be possible, and refresh cookie every 5 mintes shouldn't be needed. Only the latter is likely to be possible, but without any details of how the website creates/uses the session cookie, it's almost impossible to "how to" do this, other than to say, it's likely to be possible
